# What JQuery effect is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this really nice effect on this website:

http://www.engadget.com/

Please take a look at the IE advertisements on the top and the right side of the page.

It seems like some kind of elastic effect.

Has anybody implemented this anywhere??

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Its probably not possible to tell the effect without actually seeing it. For all I know it might just be Flash content.

Comment: Not seeing the advert, could you take a screen shot snippet and show?

Comment: Still can't see anything that looks like an elastic effect in IE or FF, can you show the two transition states.

Comment: Per the FAQ, this does not apply to the relevant topics of discussion for this site. Please consider asking it somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  this is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a SharePoint question....

It's Flash (as are all of the ads on the top of Engadget's home page). Just right click on it, and you'll see that it's Flash. That said, it's just a simple x-axis movement with easing. The core jQuery animate function could easily handle the same thing... no need for a "plugin".

Comment: Im sorry guys. I meant to put this under stack overflow. Is there a way for me to move it?